# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0'. Can work on 2.0.0.0 or 4.0.0.0?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, web-config

I have seen many answers to similar questions, but have an additional question

I developed a web site in Visual Studio 2008.  Working well on development server.  When I tried to transfer it to client's server, it is giving the error:
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0'

Noticed that client's server has version 2.0.0.0 and 4.0.0.0.  Changing my development environment to VS2010 might work, but is there any simpler solution (something like modifying web.config file)?

In short: If I develop with 3.5.0.0, can the site be loaded to 2.0.0.0 OR 4.0.0.0 by modifying the web.config file?  (It is logical that some compatibility/flexibility will be there between development and deployment set up I hope!). My web site is pretty simple, but have a MS SQL db interactions.

Comment: It's possible your client's server has .NET 2.0 and 4.0 installed, but not .NET 3.5. What OS is it running?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Thanks John Saunders for editing it.  Shall keep note in my future posts.

Comment: @Dai: Yes, clients server has not installed .NET3.5.  Should my development environment be an exact match for .NET version?

Answer (score 0):

When you read v2.0 and v4.0 from IIS settings, that simply means at least .NET 2.0 and .NET 4.0 are installed on the machine, and thus registered in IIS the two versions of CLR.

However, to run a .NET 3.5 based web application, you exactly need .NET 3.5 installed on the machine. Although installing .NET 3.5 reuses CLR 2.0, it is a must to provide System.Core which is required by your application.

Make sure you choose v2.0 for your IIS application pool, so that IIS loads CLR 2 and initializes automatically .NET 3.5 required assemblies for your application.